# PAAS DB to IAAS DB connection. Is it supported

Tags: connection, paas, iaas

Need connection from PAAS DB to IAAS DB as migrating multiple procs with OPENQUERY to remote data source (ODBC driver/Linked Server) and unable to deploy on PAAS setup.

Attempted CROSS DB QUERIES from PAAS to IAAS, setups fine but throws error when attempt to view data. 1-2 articles suggest SSL certificates on the IAAS VM but is there another way. Can we connect from PAAS to IAAS DBs?

Msg 46823, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Error retrieving data from name.region.cloudapp.azure.com.db_name.  The underlying error message received was: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)'